# tkinter button command runs function without clicking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

im brand new to GUIs and python itself really. im trying to make a simple triva game in python 3.x using tkinter. the idea is that it will have multiple questions and will tell you if you got it right or wrong as well as tell you how many you got right. the issue im running into however, is that for some reason all the buttons i have act as if they have been clicked when they havent. code below:

```
from tkinter import *
class Correct(object):
    value = True
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text


class Incorrect(object):
    value = False
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text


def check(value):
    if value == True:
        print("you picked the right answer!")
    else:
        print("sorry thats not right")


question1 = ["this is a question", Correct("right answer"), Incorrect("wrong b"), Incorrect("wrong c"),
             Incorrect("wrong d")]


master = Tk()

qlabel1 = Label(master,text=question1[0])

# buttons
choice1 = Button(master, text=question1[1].text, command=check(question1[1].value))
choice2 = Button(master, text=question1[2].text, command=check(question1[2].value))
choice3 = Button(master, text=question1[3].text, command=check(question1[3].value))
choice4 = Button(master, text=question1[4].text, command=check(question1[3].value))

# pack
qlabel1.grid(row=0, column=0)
choice1.grid(row=1, column=0)
choice2.grid(row=1, column=2)
choice3.grid(row=2, column=0)
choice4.grid(row=2, column=1)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
choice1 = Button(master, text=question1[1].text, command=lambda : check(question1[1].value))
```

After command, you must give a function (either defined with def before or with lambda on the spot).

Comment: whwt do you mean by "definee by def" ? Can you give an example?

Comment: The answer is vague, so I'd like to make is clear. We have to use either the name (without arguments)  of the def function, or use a lambda to get a reference to some function, which command is supposed to expect.